# Effective algorithm for finding out if oriented graph is unilaterally connected?

Tags: algorithm

Is there any effective algorithm for finding out if oriented graph is unilaterally connected? Unilaterally connected means that there is no more than one way from one vertex to another in graph. Thanks.

Comment: I suppose there is, since a graph where there is only one path between any two vertices is a tree. (Or a forest if the graph isn't connected.)

Comment: Is a simple cycle unilaterally connected?

Comment: @biziclop Being a tree is sufficient but not necessary: Consider a 5-node graph with edges A->C, B->C, C->D, C->E.

Comment: @Sneftel True, thanks for pointing this out. Directed graphs, duh. :) (Though on second thought I was correct in what I said: if there is **exactly** one path between any two nodes, it's a tree. But that wasn't the question.)

Comment: @Sneftel: the problem is that the term "tree" is not clearly and uniquely defined in the context of directed graphs. You have to state what you exactly mean, when you talk about tree in this context. The sample you are giving actually *is* a tree according to some definitions. Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory). That's why I suggest one should consider using more precise terms like: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arborescence_(graph_theory) or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytree. Like this you avoid this type of conflicts...

Comment: @dingalapadum It doesn't really matter. The 6-node graph with edges A->B, C->B, C->F, A->D, E->D, E->F has at most one path connecting any two vertices, yet is not a "tree" in any possible sense of the word.

Comment: @Sneftel: agreed. My problem just was "Tree is not a necessary condition, see X as a proof for that" and then actually one could say "well X actually *is* a tree". But yes, I see your point. You should have given this example right away.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Yes, simple cicle is unilaterally connected.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think your definition is wrong, I re-checked several sources and I find out that a `directed graph is connected (or "unilaterally connected") if there is a path between any two vertices`

Also there is

```
strictly unilaterally connected if it is not strongly connected
```

(and for info : `it is "strongly connected" if there is a path in both directions between any two vertices`)

It actually does not say anything about only "one path". The scrictly unilaterally connected only says that if there is a path from A to B, there is not path from B to A (but still there can be 10 paths from A to B)

---

Alghorithms:

For the "not strict" variant, you can just try doing DFS on each node. When DFS finishes on node "X", remember all the nodes "Y1, Y2, Y3..." that were not reached. For all of them, if you run DFS on them, they have to reach X, otherwise the graph is not *unilaterally connected*

For "strict" variant it is almost the same, but you also have to check nodes "Z1, Z2, Z3" - which were reached by node "X" - must not reach X, when you run DFS on them.

---

Complexity :

DFS itself is `O(n + k)` (n being nodes, k being edges), you have to run it n-times (on each node), therefore complexity is `O((n+k)*n)`

---

If you want the maximum complexity related only to nodes, it is also possible.

The maximum number of edges is `O(k) = O(n^2)`, therefore maximum complexity is `O((n+n^2)*n) = O(n^3)`

Comment: Thank you, you are completely right. But I need an algorithm to find if there is no more that one possible path between any two vertices. In my assignment the term unilaterally connected graph was defined like I wrote before.